# AWS Java SDK Cloudformation unable to describe stacks by name or Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-java-sdk

Attempting to make a simple request via the SDK is throwing a 404 Stack not found, however making the call with the exact same stack name returns the stack information as expected.

The code I'm using:

```java
  public String getStatus() {

    final DescribeStackInstanceRequest describeStackInstanceRequest =
        new DescribeStackInstanceRequest();

    describeStackInstanceRequest
        .withStackSetName("a-1593589243-example-com")
        .withStackInstanceAccount("6**********") // My AWS account ID
        .withStackInstanceRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1.getName());

    return amazonCloudFormation
        .describeStackInstance(describeStackInstanceRequest)
        .getStackInstance()
        .getStatus();
  }
```

Attempting to replace the name with the stack ID and I get back invalid regex error.

And the equvilant CLI command

```sh
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name a-1593589243-example-com
```

Using the latest version of the SDK

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:1.11.812'
```

Comment: Are you sure that CLI executes for the same region and account as the SDK?

Comment: Yeah I've triple checked that the regions all match up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `describeStackInstanceRequest` call is for [Stack Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-concepts.html#stacksets-concepts-stackset) **not** [Stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-whatis-concepts.html#w2ab1b5c15b9). These are two different things in CloudFormation.

I think the following should be used [DescribeStacksRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/opsworks/model/DescribeStacksRequest.html) or an equivalent.

Comment: Wow you're right, the class naming could have been a little more clear :(

Comment: @ChrisTurner No problem. Yes, I know, naming is confusing :-(

Comment: @ChrisTurner Did it work out? Wonder if the issue was resolved?

Comment: Yes, you were correct, I was attempting to use the wrong request class.